# How to send rate control packet in TCP/IP model?

Tags: tcp, network-core, sdn

How to send rate control(250Kb/s, 500Kb/s) packet in TCP/IP stack? Because In my understanding after tcp buffer filled then the Tx packets happening. Is my understanding is correct then How do I send the packet before the buffer full?

Comment: If I understand your question, you are talking about the PSH (push) flag.

Comment: Actually my problem is whenever I have send packets the stack fill the packets with buffer (or) window size . After buffer is full the packets get transmitted. How to control this behaviour? How to I send the packet befor the buffer is full.?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server behavior/ configuration are off-topic here, as are questions about programming, which could be asked on [so].

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the PSH flag to tell the receiver to process the data even though the buffer is not full.  [Here is a good explanation](http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/mar/2/tcp-flags-psh-and-urg/).

> Consider what would happen to a Telnet session, for instance, if TCP
>   waited until there was enough data to fill a packet before it would
>   send one: You would have to type over a thousand characters before the
>   first packet would make it to the remote device. Not very useful.
>
> This is where the PSH flag comes in. The socket that TCP makes
>   available at the session level can be written to by the application
>   with the option of "pushing" data out immediately, rather than waiting
>   for additional data to enter the buffer. When this happens, the PSH
>   flag in the outgoing TCP packet is set to 1 (on). Upon receiving a
>   packet with the PSH flag set, the other side of the connection knows
>   to immediately forward the segment up to the application.

Comment: Please explain with some sample c code, Because when I send the packet with write function always the push flag is set by default. So I am not differentiate the operation of setting push flag.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written C code in over thirty years.  If you have a programming question, this is the wrong forum for it.  you should try Stack Overflow.